# How to rotate a light around a object using geometry node?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I have a monkey right on the origin. I want to create an animation that a light is orbiting around the monkey following the path indicated by the cones in the second picture.

I have sucessfully created the path(cones) but I dont know how to make light following the path.

In addition, is it necessary to make this geometry node of lights in the object PLANE rather than the monkey? I tried to have multiple output of geometry (monkey + cone/lights) but it does not work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: since light has no geometry i think it is not possible to make the light follow a path with GN. But there might be a workaround. You can of course let any geometry (cube, plane, robot, Space station) let follow a path.

Comment: @Chris Thanks. I found a tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwjFmnY-d6M. It seems the position and rotation can be set, but I cannot figure out how to orbit around my own object.

Comment: wow, didn't know it works with collections, that's great to know!!!

Comment: I think GN is overkill for this task, you can use Follow Path constraint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

With the value in multiply you can change the speed.

result:

[image]

If you want a "smoother" animation, increase the vertices in Mesh circle.

Comment: I want to elaborate the answer, Scene time is 3.1 node. If you are using 3.0 you can make the same by entering `#frame` in the field of Input ⇾ integer node.

Comment: @Crantisz : yes, that’s true! Thank you for that important information!!